# How to find the tension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A massless rod of length L attached to mass m and with axle to cart of mass M. The cart has a shape of equilateral triangle (edge L). the cart is at rest and its center of mass is above x=0 and a rod is perpendicular to the ground. the cart is free to move without friction. at time t=0 the mass m is released and starts to fall to the left. at time t=τ the rod is parallel to the ground. 
 Why the tension from the stick at time $t=\tau$ is $T=mv^2/L=2mg$ and not $T=mv^2/L=mg$? 
[image]

Comment: @ Wojciech What is the tension that the cart feels?

Comment: I think I've seen a different question on this case a couple days ago. Is it homework? Also please elaborate on the answers You provide, why You think it should be one and not another.

Comment: mv^2/L is the radial force that need to be equated with the tension force....but the torque mgsin 90 = mg..I have no idea why it is 2mg may you give an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the tension will be equal to centrifugal force $T=mv^2/L$. Try to calculate velocity from energy conservation law $mgL=mv^2/2$ and then see what happens.